# What ports does an LG TV open?

Tags: networking, smart-tv

I'm seeing some unexpected ports open on an LG TV model 47LN5750-UH, serial 311MXTC1E969. Below is the result from a `nmap` scan.

```
Nmap scan report for 172.16.4.4
Host is up (0.00021s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
1148/tcp open  elfiq-repl
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
MAC Address: CC:2D:8C:59:9B:3C (LG Electronics)
```

I can't find information on [LG TV TCP ports](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22tg%20tv%22%20tcp%20ports+site%3Alg.com). I also cannot find useful information on [TCP/1148 - Elfiq Replication Service](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+"Elfiq+Replication+Service"). I did find some talk about TCP/1148 being part of a botnet.

My questions are:

- What ports do LG TVs open
- What are the services associated with those ports

And specific to the tv above:

- Is TCP/1148 expected to be open?
- What service is provided on the port?

Comment: As per [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?&page=18) its the "Elfiq Replication Service". But I could not find any reference to this service. May be you can use this info further. Can't tell if that port should be really open.

Comment: Have you tried [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) ?

Comment: @sob - Forgive my ignorance... Are you stating that the tv opens TCP/1148 for the Elfiq Replication Service? Or are you guessing the service based on the port number? Can you provide a reference or citation? (I was able to find lots of hits for the known service name, but they most mostly useless references. If you are stating it as fact, then my next question is, what is the Elfiq Replication Service. I can't seem to find information on it, either).

Comment: Re: using Wireshark to investigate...Run Wireshark as admin in promiscuous mode on a computer connected to the same subnet as your TV, and use the filters to only display packets with the LG TV's IP as the source or destination address.

Comment: Port 3001 works for my LG LB650V smart WebOS TV.

Answer (score 6):

I found this list:

```
Port Scanning host results

Open TCP Port:     1061
Open TCP Port:     1424
Open TCP Port:     1900 ssdp
Open TCP Port:     1970
Open TCP Port:     3000 ws
Open TCP Port:     3001 wss
Open TCP Port:     9955
Open TCP Port:     9998
Open TCP Port:     18181
Open TCP Port:     36866

 UDP:

 Sends data to 
 239.255.255.250:1900 ssdp traffic
```

> 192.168.1.255:9956 and 224.0.0.113:9956. Port 9956 and the contents show this is alljoyn-traffic,--

Source:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/lgtv

Comment: For anyone else here wondering how this was retrieved (on macOS) open the Network Utility app and open the Port Scan tab, then enter the TV's IP address and hit scan

Comment: also i have seen LG TV spit out 56700/udp IPv4 broadcast in attempt to get ahold of a LifX lightbulb protocol server (typically Amazon Echo, Google Home).